# Regex Question - Searching for this or that?

Tags: regex

I want to search a file for either a character at the beginning of the line, or a blank or empty line. So for example, let's assume the end of line char is LF = chr(10)

In the text below, I want the count of the results to equal (5). All lines beginning with the string "T" and empty but for spaces or blank lines.

```
=====FILE======  
This is good (count this one 1.)  
    --- one or more spaces (count this one 2.)  
Not so good  
This is also good (count this one 3.)
- intentionally blank -  (count next two 4.)
- intentionally blank -  (.5)
Can't be good  
=====END FILE===
```

Comment: Are spaces allowed before a "T"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/^(T|\s*$)/
```

Comment: Note that \s is a perl-ism and though supported by more and more regexp engines, it's not supported by them all.  yet.

Comment: @Wes Hardaker: We need specifics from the OP before we start criticizing.

Answer (score 1):

To match the above:

```
^(T.*| *)$
```

Comment: This doesn't match the second line.

Comment: Yes, it does.  I even tested it.  (make sure you realize that his text after the -s need to be removed as they're comments).

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job:

```
/^([T ].+|$)/
```

here is a sample Perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.12.0;

my $count;
while(<DATA>) {
    $count++ if /^([T ].+|$)/;
}
say $count;

__DATA__
This is good (count this one 1.)  

Not so good  
This is also good (count this one 3.)


Can't be good
```

**output: 5**

Comment: You have misunderstood the requirements.  The test case in the question would, optimally, be better, but I have to agree with the others that "--- one or more spaces" is a comment and not part of the test data, just like "- intentionally blank -" and everything in parens.